# How do I get MaterialUI XGrid filters to filter by renderCell parameters instead of the backend data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using MaterialUI XGrid to display rows of information. Currently when I am trying to filter items, I can't filter by what the cell displays, only by the back end row.

For example, I have a column named Upload Status. In the backend, the values are PENDING, PASS, and FAIL for the display values In Progress, Succeeded, and Failed respectively. When I filter in the front end, I can't filter by In Progress, Succeeded, and Failed, only the back end values PENDING, PASS, and FAIL. How can I change how data is filtered with MaterialUI XGrid?

Here's the code for the Upload Status Column:

```
{
      field: "Upload Status",
      flex: 1,
      renderHeader: () => <FormattedMessage id={"Upload Status"} />,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        let parameter = params.row["Upload Status"];
        let cell = "";
        
        if (parameter === "PENDING") {
          cell = "In Progress";
        } else if (parameter === "PASS") {
          cell = "Succeeded";
        } else if (parameter === "FAIL") {
          cell = "Failed";
        }
        return (
          cell
        );
  },
},
```

This image shows how I want it to filter, but it's failing.

[image: Upload Image filter failing.]

This is how the column looks.

[image: How Upload Status column looks.]

I want the filter command from the first picture to filter to only rows that have "In Progress" in their Upload Status cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`renderCell` is primarily for customizing the rendering to add additional elements rather than just rendering a string. In order to customize the string that is displayed, you should use [valueGetter](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/columns/#value-getter) instead. In my example below, the data contains `UploadStatusCode` and then the `"Upload Status"` field provides a `valueGetter` to translate the code to the text to display. The filtering then works on the text returned by `valueGetter`.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";

const columns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
  {
    field: "firstName",
    headerName: "First name",
    flex: 1,
    editable: true
  },
  {
    field: "lastName",
    headerName: "Last name",
    flex: 1,
    editable: true
  },
  {
    field: "Upload Status",
    headerName: "Upload Status",
    flex: 1,
    editable: false,
    valueGetter: (params) => {
      let parameter = params.row["UploadStatusCode"];
      let cell = "";

      if (parameter === "PENDING") {
        cell = "In Progress";
      } else if (parameter === "PASS") {
        cell = "Succeeded";
      } else if (parameter === "FAIL") {
        cell = "Failed";
      }
      return cell;
    }
  }
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: "Snow", firstName: "Jon", UploadStatusCode: "PENDING" },
  {
    id: 2,
    lastName: "Lannister",
    firstName: "Cersei",
    UploadStatusCode: "PASS"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    lastName: "Lannister",
    firstName: "Jaime",
    UploadStatusCode: "FAIL"
  },
  { id: 4, lastName: "Stark", firstName: "Arya", UploadStatusCode: "PENDING" },
  {
    id: 5,
    lastName: "Targaryen",
    firstName: "Daenerys",
    UploadStatusCode: "PASS"
  },
  { id: 6, lastName: "Melisandre", firstName: null, UploadStatusCode: "PASS" },
  {
    id: 7,
    lastName: "Clifford",
    firstName: "Ferrara",
    UploadStatusCode: "PENDING"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    lastName: "Frances",
    firstName: "Rossini",
    UploadStatusCode: "FAIL"
  },
  { id: 9, lastName: "Roxie", firstName: "Harvey", UploadStatusCode: "PASS" }
];

export default function DataGridDemo() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit DataGrid filtering]

Comment: Thank you. I just needed to change `renderCell` to `valueGetter` and it worked!