# Material UI data grid filter not working when using renderCell in a field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working in a react project and i am using Data Grid. There are several fields on that grid , the filter is working good with the other fields but not working with the field that use renderCell. Is there any way to filter the movie title?
here is the code :

```
 const columns = [
{ field: "_id", headerName: "ID", width: 110 },
{
  field: "movie",
  headerName: "Movie",
  width: 240,

  renderCell: (params) => {
    return (
      <div className={Style.usercell}>
        <img src={params.row.featuredImg} alt="" />
        <span>{params.row.title}</span>
      </div>
    );
  },
},
{ field: "genre", headerName: "Genre", width:  120 },
{ field: "year", headerName: "Year", width:  120 } ]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68550751/how-do-i-get-materialui-xgrid-filters-to-filter-by-rendercell-parameters-instead

Answer (score 6):

Add this:

```
  renderCell: (params) => {
    return (
      <div className={Style.usercell}>
        <img src={params.row.featuredImg} alt="" />
        <span>{params.row.title}</span>
      </div>
    );
  },
  valueGetter: (params) => params.row.title
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: this works by rendering the cell to display html and the value is set by the getter